# How to find (and rename) file and folder names with octl characters

Tags: unix, character-encoding

I accidentally copied files with the wrong encoding, so instead of utf-8 the file and folder names appear to be encoded with octl, i.e. they are for example called `L\334ten.txt` instead of `Löten.txt`. I would like to (at least) find all affected files and folders, ideally I would be able to rename the files automatically (so `\334` to `ö` and so on). If changing the encoding is an option, that's of course okay, too. A Bash solution would be best, but I am open to using python or something similar.

I tried identifying the files/folders using grep/find, but sadly without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty oneliner:

```
for file in $(find . -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*[\][0-9]{3}.*"); \
do \
OLD_NAME=$(basename $file); \
NEW_NAME=$(echo $OLD_NAME | \
sed 's/\\337/ß/g' | \
sed 's/\\344/ä/g' | \
sed 's/\\366/ö/g' | \
sed 's/\\374/ü/g'); \
mv $file $(dirname $file)/$NEW_NAME; \
done
```

Proof:

```
$ touch 'W\344rme.txt' 'L\366ten.txt' 'l\366tf\344hige.txt'
$ ls
'L\366ten.txt'  'l\366tf\344hige.txt'  'W\344rme.txt'
$ copy_paste_oneliner_here
$ ls
Löten.txt  lötfähige.txt  Wärme.txt
```

#### UPDATE:

@rt87 If I understood right your comment, it's possible to emulate your weird filenames:

```
$ touch $(echo "Löten.txt" | iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1)
```

So, now we have a file with incorrect encoded name for UTF-8 locale - `L�ten.txt`. In the terminal you can see:

```
$ ls
'L'$'\366''ten.txt'
```

Thus, you can get back your files with another oneliner:

```
for file in *.*; do mv "$file" "$(echo $file | iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8)"; done
```

In our test examle we got:

```
$ ls
Löten.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, but actually, when I do this, the files are e.g. called "L\\334ten.txt", so the backslash gets escaped. Also, they are shown as just that. My problem just yielded some weird placeholder character (not "?", I don't know what it's called, haven't seen it before)

Comment: The update actually reproduced my problem and, more importantly, solved it! Thank you so very much =)!